# react-native crash after update to Xcode 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I have just updated XCode to version 13.0 and now when I run my react native app from xcode or VSCode the Build Fails. This is also a clean install of a react-native ios project.

[xcode build errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o3Or.png)

[additional build errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1dnV.png)

Comment: Which react-native version of do you use?

Comment: React native version: 0.65

Comment: have you checked the following: https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/issues/238#issuecomment-890367992

Answer (score 0):

With React-Native 0.65 there is a link problem with Swift (https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/issues/238#issuecomment-890367992). Please also check the Upgrade Helper and current info on the RN Blog (https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/08/17/version-065).